# Why is a loop doing this in C++

Tags: c++

Alright, beginner, take it easy. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int x = 0;
    bool while1 = true;
    while (while1)
    {
        cout << x << "\n";
        sleep(200);
        if (x < 10)
        {
            while1 = true;
        }
        else if (x >= 10)
        {
            while1 = false;
        }
        x = x+1;
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

Alright, so I don't understand why the program even gets x to 10 if I'm have the if statements check if x < 10 before I have 1 added to x... please explain.

Comment: Indentation, indentation, indentation...

Comment: `while = false;` are you sure this code compiles ?

Comment: This won't even compile. Start with this + identation

Comment: There's a lot of fail here: while1 = truel <- no semicolon, "\n" Sleep <- no semicolon, while = false <- should be while1 ... PS that edit was rubbish, it corrected most code issues :/

Comment: `for (int x = 0; x <= 10; ++x) {std::cout << x << "\n"; Sleep(200);}` - There's your whole code. You might be happy with the knowledge that you can remove that giant windows.h inclusion and use `std::this_thread::sleep_for` in C++11.

Comment: I fixed your code's formatting and syntax. Code you post to Stack Overflow should be formatted properly by the poster.

Answer (score 5):

Order of operations is:

- 1) stop the loop if 3) found x was >= 10 (if `while1` is false)
- 2) print out x
- 3) check if x >= 10 here and set `while1` to false if it is
- 4) increment x

When x is 9 we proceed as follows:

- Don't stop the loop (`while1` is true)
- Print out 9
- x is not >= 10 yet, set `while1` to true
- x is incremented to 10
- Don't stop the loop (`while1` is true)
- Print out 10
- x is now >= 10, set `while1` to false
- x is incremented to 11
- We stop the loop as `while1` was set to false

So, x gets printed out when it's 10. The problem is that, the way you check and act on the check, you do one loop too many before stopping.

One way to fix this is

```
while (x < 10)
{
    cout << x << "\n";
    Sleep(200);
    x = x+1;
}
```

Now the loop will not execute on the same pass through that x is 10, not the pass immediately afterwards.

Even better is this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
{
    cout << x << "\n";
    Sleep(200);
}
```

Which is clearer about its intent over looping over incrementing values of x.

Answer (score 0):

The program gets `x` to `10` because the `x = x + 1` happens outside of the `if`.
So during one execution of the loop, it will check, then if x is less than 10 it will make `while1` true. Otherwise it makes `while1` false. After that it increases `x` no matter what.
Then it repeats this process if `while` is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (x >= 10)
{
    while1 = false;
}
x = x+1;
```

I understand the question as: *Why is x getting to 10?* Is this correct?

Your while loop does not immediately exit when setting while1 to false. So of course x will equal to 10 after exiting the loop as x is increase after checking that, so x will in fact be 11 after this code segment.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want x to be printed after x >= 10, do the checking after you increment x.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main(
{
    int x = 0;
    bool while1 = true;
    while (while1)
    {
        cout << x << "\n"
        x++;
        Sleep(200);
        if (x < 10)
        {
            while1 = true;
        }
        else if (x >= 10)
        {
            while1 = false;
        }
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if x>=10 in the loop than obviously the loop will iterate one more time when it reaches to 10 in the while loop

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is:

1. asking the program to print the value of x
2. check to see if x is less than 10
3. if it is, set while1 to true. Else set while1 to false
4. increase the value of x by 1 (regardless of whether while1 is true or false)

...

- At the start of the 10th loop, x = 9.
- Prints out 9
- Since x is still less than 10, while1 remains true
- At the end of the 10th loop, x = 10 and while1 = true

Your program start another loop since while1 = true

- At the start of the 11th loop, x = 10.
- Prints out 10
- Since x is now equal to 10, while1 is set to false
- At the end of the 11th loop, x = 11 and while1 = false

Best thing to do is to just

```
int x = 0;
while(x < 10)
{
   cout << x << endl;      //this way your program will only print 0 to 9
   sleep(200);
   x++;                    //this is the same as x = x+1
}
```

If you insist on using your own code, I guess you can replace your while1 = false with break;

```
else if (x >= 10)
{
    break;
}
```

break; will let you break out of the while loop if x >= 10 without increasing x or going through the loop again...

Should be safe unless you are going to do more things in that while loop...